# how to set Imageview right end aligned to textview in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_12">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ln1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/convert_points_layout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cl_18"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            style="@style/Typeface.Small.Bold.TextMidGrey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="jkhdsfjkhj kljsdlf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            style="@style/Typeface.Small.TextMidGrey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8"
            android:text="@string/convert_to_voucher_message"
            tools:text="Once you have 150 points, you can convert them to a voucher." />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            style="@style/Typeface.Small.TextMidGrey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8"
            tools:text="Final points collection this quarter: 21/1/17" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_arrow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="120"
        android:gravity="right">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info_Imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_arrow_right" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my xml i want set right end infor_imageview aligned to text3 programmatically i am tried to get margin of text3  so that i can set right end to text3 but unable to do please suggest me how to  do this .first i want to get margin of text 3 and then i want set right end of text 3 info_imageview.

Comment: Do you want the left edge of the info_imageview to be aligned to the right edge of the text3 textview?

Comment: if you only want to set an arrow to the right of txt view .. you can try `android:drawable_end="@drawable/your_image"` to the textview  .

Comment: this is fine but i want set icon bit top on textview

Answer (score 1):

one relative layout will do or use ConstraintLayout much better

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Text 2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Text 3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: let me check this thanx

Comment: android:drawable_end="@drawable/your_image" this work for me but just i need bit top that image inside textview

Comment: then add margin on your first textview

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion on the choice of layout, you could use the ConstraintLayout which provides consistent and more customization ability so that the layouts are always show as it is intended.  Using relativelayout could result different when open in different screen size especially in your case (right end aligned to textview).

Comment: we cant use ConstraintLayout thats a reason i am trying to do in this way

Comment: android:drawable_end="@drawable/your_image" this work for me but just i need bit top that image inside textview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `LinearLayout` throughout, then you can do so in this manner. I've removed some xml to clarify.

Note the weights. It looks like in your code you may be using weights incorrectly. It is a ratio of sizes. If one element is weight 1 and another is weight 2, the first will be twice as big as the second.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_arrow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info_imageview"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: let me check this one thanx

Comment: android:drawable_end="@drawable/your_image" this work for me but just i need bit top that image inside textview

Comment: Can you draw what you would like and upload the picture? I'm unsure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Left and side aligned 3 text view and Right and side display image view like this:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="firstName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lName_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name_tv"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="LastName"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lName_tv"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Email"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy my code and check u want to get output as your expectation or not, not then inform me i have another suggestion for you

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="jkhdsfjkhj kljsdlf" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="convert_to_voucher_message"
                tools:text="Once you have 150 points, you can convert them to a voucher."/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView        
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                tools:text="Final points collection this quarter: 21/1/17" />
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/info_Imageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icons_right" />
    </LinearLayout>        
</LinearLayout>
```

and yes you add your styles or image coz i am use my image and remove your styles so